# Python: Surpass SSL verification with urllib3

Tags: python, python-2.7, ssl, urllib, urllib3

Connectiing to SSL server is throwing an error:

> error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate
>   verify failed

I'm using this urllib3 python library for connecting to server, using this method:

```
urllib3.connectionpool.connection_from_url(['remote_server_url'], maxsize=2)
```

How can i ignore SSL verification? Or is there another step for doing this?

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you want to disable certificate verification? Have you considered looking for the real problem instead of trying to work around it? Disabling certificate verification effectively disables any security, so you could use plain http instead of https then.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Because at the moment i need a quick solution that works, not the best one. I'm aware of the security hole surpassing cerificare verification but i think it won't make any problem at the moment. Web server i'm connecting is forcing https, where i get an error abowe. Can you tell me work around for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to force urllib3 to use an unverified HTTPSConnection object by overriding the static `ConnectionCls` property of any ConnectionPool instance. For example:

```
from urllib3.connection import UnverifiedHTTPSConnection
from urllib3.connectionpool import connection_from_url

# Get a ConnectionPool object, same as what you're doing in your question
http = connection_from_url(remote_server_url, maxsize=2)

# Override the connection class to force the unverified HTTPSConnection class
http.ConnectionCls = UnverifiedHTTPSConnection

# Make requests as normal...
r = http.request(...)
```

For additional reference, you can [check some of our tests](https://github.com/shazow/urllib3/blob/ba06933310dbd5764e2baa53f3505cf54eae56f7/test/with_dummyserver/test_https.py#L106) which do similar overriding.

I've [opened an issue to improve our documentation](https://github.com/shazow/urllib3/issues/403#issuecomment-45660345) on how and when this should be done. We always appreciate pull requests, if you'd like to contribute. :)

Comment: Got `AttributeError: 'HTTPSConnection' object has no attribute 'cert_reqs'` :(

Answer (score 0):

you can also install the certificate library which might help

```
pip install certifi
```